# How does $SL(2,\Bbb{Z})$ act on $q$-series?

Tags: modular-forms

A modular form is a function $f(\tau)$ that obeys

$$f\left(\frac{a \tau+b}{c \tau+d}\right) = \frac1{(c \tau+d)^n} f(\tau).$$

for some integer $n$, and some subgroup of matrices $\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}\in SL(2,\Bbb{Z}).$  Usually, $f$ is expanded into a $q$-series

$$f = ... + a_0 + a_1 q + a_2 q^2 + ...$$

(I am not sure wether it is ok for this series to have a tail) where $q = \exp(2\pi i \tau)$.

Can you write down a formula for how $\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}$ acts, directly on $q$-series?

In author words, is $\Bbb{C}[[q]]$ or $\Bbb{C}((q))$ a $SL(2,\Bbb{Z})$-module?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I took the liberty of TeXifying your post. Have you looked at e.g. Apostol's book on [Modular functions and Dirichlet series](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387971278) for examples? IIRC it is not at all obvious.

Comment: IIRC it should be $q=e^{2\pi i \tau}$, and the Laurent series should begin from somewhere (a pole of a finite order at $q=0$) as $f$ should be meromorphic.

Comment: Thank you Profesor Lahtonen.  2 pi i makes sense, then the function is invariant for ((1 1)(0 1)) automatically.  (Maybe (2 pi k i tau) would also  make sense, if the subgroup of SL(2,Z) did not contain ((1 1)(0 1)) but did contain ((1 k)(0 1)) ?)

Comment: But I don't understand how ((0 1)(-1 0)) acts on q-series.

Comment: In general if $f$ is holomorphic on $\Im(z) > 0$ then $f(z)+z^{-k} f(-1/z)$ is invariant under the $|_k \gamma$ operator, $ \gamma. z = -1/z$. Modular forms are the very special case where $f(z)+z^{-k} f(-1/z)$ is also $T$-periodic.

Comment: Reuns, what is T-periodic?

Comment: If we could, it would make the study of modular forms a lot easier!